# Hiding only Empty tables that have the same css class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've searched this forum and clicked almost every link even relevant to my problem so if I missed a blatant post about this I apologize. Here's my situation. I have some dynamically generated tables that all have the same css class (they have to for a check box I have that hides them). The thing is I want to hide tables that don't have any data in them but show the ones that do. I have pieced together some code but what I have ends up hiding all tables with the same CSS class if one of the tables are empty. I say empty but they all have at least one td and I'm counting if it only has one td to hide the table.

Here is the code I have at the moment....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.devTable').each(function (i) {
            //select all tds in this column
            var tds = $(this).parents('.devTable')
                     .find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
            if (tds.length <= 1) {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

I know it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: `$('.devTable').not(":has(td:nth-child(even))").hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can use `filter()`. I am basing this on any table of the class with no more than one `<td>`

```
$('.devTable').filter(function(){
     return $(this).find('td').length <=1;
}).hide();
```

Reference: [**filter() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: please provide html in the future

Comment: sorry, I was editing the wrong post. Your code worked perfect. Much thanks. You saved me a ton of time.